# How to combine two commands in linux?

Tags: linux, command

I would like to know how to combine two commands. For example if I need to return the number of lines and number of words, how can I use a single command to get the data?

When I do I am using two commands separately. Here is the way how I have used.

`wc -l filename`  (this is to get the number of lines)
`wc -w filename`  (this is to get the number of words)

Is there any way to get both using a single command?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
wc -l -w filename
```

It uses both flags and returns both numbers.

Example input:

```
wc -l -w /home/administrator/Desktop/myFile.txt
```

Example output:

```
9 13 /home/administrator/Desktop/myFile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks it works. 
I got one other problem too. That is I want to check particular file size, current capacity and also available capacity. What command should I have to use?
Now I am using du -h  but i did not work.

Comment: @Birzigli You should open a new question for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the commands that need to be chained/concatenated, the following could also be used

command A **;** command B
will run the first command regardless of the success/failure of the second command

command A **&** command B
This command sends a process/script/command to the background.

command A **&&** command B
will run command B only if command A succeeded

command A **|** command B
The output of the first command acts as input to the second command.

command A **||** command B
The command succeeding this operator is only executed if the command preceding it has failed